# initializing the button

Tags: c#

hello I came from the world of c/c++, I have the following snippet of the code, is it good idea to initialize button this way? thanks in advance

```
private Button initializeButton() {
    Button button = new Button();

    button.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.System;
    button.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 16);
    button.Name = "button";
    button.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(168, 24);
    button.TabIndex = 5;
    button.Text = "button";

    return button;
}
```

Comment: What's `portButton`? Did you mean `button`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this at all. But, you can use a shortcut syntax too:

```
return new Button {
    FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.System,
    Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 16),
    Name = "button",
    Size = new System.Drawing.Size(168, 24),
    TabIndex = 5,
    Text = "button"
};
```

Comment: is it possible to assign event this way?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, and if you want to make it shorter you can use something like this:

```
    private Button initializeButton() {
        return new Button() {
            FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.System,
            Name = "button",
            ....
        };
    }
```

You might need to [dispose this button later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014286/removing-dynamically-created-controls-c/2014427#2014427) if you don't add it parent's [Controls collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385060/making-windows-forms-controls-read-only-and-idisposable/1386472#1386472).